# Using Linq to select multiple items per iteration?

Tags: c#, linq

Per iteration, this query creates an EmailRecipient for each populated address.  Can it be done without the multiple iteration?

```
var addedRecipients = (from oldRecip in oldEmailRecipients
                        where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(oldRecip.EmailAddress1)
                        select new EmailRecipient
                            {
                                UserName = oldRecip.UserName,
                                EmailAddress = oldRecip.EmailAddress1
                            }
                ).Union(from oldRecip in oldEmailRecipients
                        where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(oldRecip.EmailAddress2)
                        select new EmailRecipient
                            {
                                UserName = oldRecip.UserName,
                                EmailAddress = oldRecip.EmailAddress2
                            });
```

Comment: What should happen if both `EmailAddress1` and `EmailAddress2` have values for a particular recipient? Do you want to get 1 or 2 `EmailRecipient` results for that recipient?

Comment: If both EmailAddress1 and EmailAddress2 are populated, emit an EmailRecipient for each.  So there can be 0, 1, or 2 emits per oldEmailRecipient.  10 rows can generate potentially 20 EmailRecipients.

Comment: In this case, the answer by octavioccl is what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method:

```
var addedRecipients = oldEmailRecipients.SelectMany(e=>
                                         {
                                          var result= new List<EmailRecipient>();
                                          if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.EmailAddress1))
                                          {
                                             result.Add(new EmailRecipient
                                                            {
                                                              UserName = e.UserName,
                                                              EmailAddress = e.EmailAddress1
                                                            });
                                          }
                                          if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.EmailAddress2))
                                          {
                                             result.Add(new EmailRecipient
                                                            {
                                                                UserName = e.UserName,
                                                                EmailAddress = e.EmailAddress2
                                                            });
                                          }
                                          return result;
                                         });
```

### Update

The solution that I show above only works in Linq to Objects. Your comment suggest me you are using EF. A simple solution could be call `AsEnumerable` method before `SelectMany` to make the switch to Linq to Objects, but that could end harming your performance if you are not filtering your recipients first.

Another solution could be selecting only data that you need first from you server before of call `SelectMany` to not load other columns you don't need in this case:

```
...Where(...)
  .Select(r=>new{UserName=r.UserName,
                 EmailAddress1=r.EmailAddress1,
                 EmailAddress2=r.EmailAddress2 })
  .AsEnumerable()
  .SelectMany(...);
```

Comment: Good answer +1. You might want to format the answer to make it more readable.

Comment: sweet and succinct.  except "A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree."  possibly something on my end.

Comment: oh, are you using EF?

Comment: Please downvoter, could you explain why to improve my answer?

Comment: @octavioccl FYI, I only upvoted you!  Figured out the AsEnumerable minutes after it popped up was due to EF.  Your response was well-crafted imho.

Answer (score 1):

Sticking with query syntax, and making sure to only process `oldEmailRecipients` items who have either a non-null/whitespace `EmailAddress1` or a non-null/whitespace `EmailAddress2`:

```
var addedRecipients =
    from oldEmail in oldEmailRecipients
    let hasEmail1 = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(oldEmail.EmailAddress1)
    let hasEmail2 = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(oldEmail.EmailAddress2)
    where hasEmail1 || hasEmail2
    let emailUserNameCombos = hasEmail1 && hasEmail2
        ? new[]
        {
            new {Email = oldEmail.EmailAddress1, oldEmail.UserName},
            new {Email = oldEmail.EmailAddress2, oldEmail.UserName}
        }
        : hasEmail1
            ? new[] {new {Email = oldEmail.EmailAddress1, oldEmail.UserName}}
            : new[] {new {Email = oldEmail.EmailAddress2, oldEmail.UserName}}
    from emailUsername in emailUserNameCombos
    select new EmailRecipient 
        {
            UserName = emailUsername.UserName,
            EmailAddress = emailUsername.Email
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build an inline array to add both emails and flatten them out using SelectMany.

```
var addedRecipients = from oldRecip in oldEmailRecipients
    let emails =
        new[] {oldRecip.EmailAddress1, oldRecip.EmailAddress2}.Where(e => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e))
    from email in emails
    where emails.Any()
    select new EmailRecipient
    {
        UserName = oldRecip.UserName,
        EmailAddress = email
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

When your `EmailRecipient` has more than two email address then you could do this:

```
// Just building a pseudo dataclass
List<Recipient> oldEmailRecipients = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(item => new Recipient()
{
    Name = "Recipient" + item,
    EmailAddress1 = "pseudo" + item + "@gmail.com",
    EmailAddress2 = "pseudo" + (item + 1) + "@gmail.com",
    //EmailAddress3 = "pseudo" + (item + 2) + "@gmail.com",
    EmailAddress3 = "",
    EmailAddress4 = "pseudo" + (item + 3) + "@gmail.com",
} ).ToList( )

// create anonymous object for each recipient and a list of valid adresses
var query = from mailRecipients in oldEmailRecipients
            select new
            {
                Name = mailRecipients.Name,
                Addresses = new List<string>()
                {
                    mailRecipients.EmailAddress1,
                    mailRecipients.EmailAddress2,
                    mailRecipients.EmailAddress3,
                    mailRecipients.EmailAddress4
                }.Where(item => string.IsNullOrEmpty( item ) == false )
            };

// create an EmailRecipient for each valid combination
var final = from item in query
            from address in item.Addresses
            select new EmailRecipient
            {
                Name = item.Name,
                Address = address
            };
```